# How to prevent a newly create window to change its content when switching between workspaces?

Tags: python, scripting, windows, workspaces

[image]
hello, how do i prevent this behavior of any newly created window /window dupplication ? i want the content of the window to stay the same when switching from workspaces to workspaces.

can it be done within blender ? can it be done with python?

Comment: No, you can't use edit mode and object mode in the same time in different windows.

Comment: that's not what im asking

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to create an extra camera and lock it to the view. Then you'll have to make the camera active in each workspace to be able to switch between the workspaces, preserving the angle of view. A bit annoying workflow, but it helps to solve the problem